# python tools for Visual studio 2015 debugging slow when importing gensim package

Tags: python, visual-studio, gensim, ptvs

I am using PTVS in VS 2015 to write python code. When I write import gensim library and start debugging using F5, Debugger takes around 5 mins to load the library and move to next line.

```
from gensim import utils
```

a. How do I fix this problem? 
b. If I start without debug(ctrl+F5) its fast to load. What code I should write to pause execution, attach the debugger then continue.

Answer (score 1):

PTVS team has fixed this in VS 2017 15.4 edition which is currently a preview edition of VS.